# Web API controller action keeps failing

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

My client code

```
function RequestMO()
{
    var moId = $("#moId").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:58019/Bank/GetMoneyOrderRequest',
        data: {id = moId}
    }).done(function (data) {

        alert("Money Order Requested!!");
    }).error(function (data) {
        alert("Money Order Not Found!!");
    });


}
```

My Web API controller action

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [Route("GetMoneyOrderRequest")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMoneyOrderRequest(int id)
    {
        try
        {

            bankRepo.UpdateMoneyOrderRequest(id);


            return Ok("Success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
```

There is a [RoutePrefix("Bank")] at the top of the Controller. The request is being sent from another application. I keep getting a '500 Internal Server error'. I know it is not being returned by the controller because I have a break point as soon as it enters the 'try-catch'. I also tried to use POST but it is still not working. Why is it failing?

Comment: You'll need to debug to find the exception causing the 500 error. Try adding a global `HandleErrors` attribute.

Comment: Give us the details of the exception.  You should be able to get that detail via your breakpoint and the debugger.

Comment: Are you sure `moId` variable is filled ? Try changing to `url: 'http://localhost:58019/Bank/GetMoneyOrderRequest?id=100'` for testing, and see if you hit the breakpoint.